# Android transparent AlertDialog in XML

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to make an `AlertDialog` transparent using only XML attributes in its layout or style, not in java / kotlin code?

I know I can make the `AlertDialog` transparent in code like this:

```
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

But I have some constraints and **cannot use this or any other Java / Kotlin** way.

I have tried various styling attributes in vain:

```
<style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:panelColorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a different `parent`, such as one of the `Translucent` ones?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: You can try this                                  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));